# Javascript Regex: Validate phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a 11 digit phone number that must start with 09 (i.e. 09123456789) using javascript for client side check.

this is my code:

```
function validatePhone(number) {
    var re = /^09[0-9]{9}$/;
    return re.test(number);
}
```

It worked correctly as far as I know at first but now it return invalid for any number I use.  Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?
By the way as I'm using jQuery, if there is a better way with jquery that would be much better.

Comment: That code works correctly. Your bug is elsewhere, I think.

Comment: What number did you use? Also, jquery is not the magical solution to all problems. Careful debugging is.

Comment: Next time use actual code that represents the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are sending an integer in the argument, pass it as a string

```
function validatePhone(number) {
    var re = /^09[0-9]{9}$/;
    return re.test(number);
}

​alert(validatePhone('09123456789'));​​​
// returns true    
alert(validatePhone(09123456789));    
// returns false    ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bFwd/

Comment: yep, you are right the problem is i was checking .text() instead of .val() . my bad programming for long hours causes this stupid mistakes. Thanks alot

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, Atif: Both `.text()` and `.val()` return a string. The actual issue is that `.text()` doesn't return the value, so you were getting an empty string, not a number.

Comment: @Asad, sorry about that, was trying to demonstrate quickly and copy and pasted everything..

Comment: @user1689607 this is what exactly happen ... if answer +1

Comment: @NullPointer: Thanks, but I'd rather see the question deleted to reduce SO clutter.

Comment: however It solved my problem. in 5 minutes I will be able to choose it as correct answer.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: It didn't solve your problem. Switching from `.text()` to `.val()` solved it. ...that is unless you were first converting the input to a number. This is why you should include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: yes thats right, but it would take me a while, as I was poking this regex ;)

Comment: @user1689607 .text() wont work if the OP is trying to send values from a form INPUT like text box

Comment: ...you should at least update your answer to reflect the actual solution. As it stands, it could be confusing to future readers.

Comment: I don't think so, because OP never mentioned about `.text() / .val()` issue in the question, so my answer makes perfect context to the current question (unless he edits the actual question)

Comment: I see your point. It's a valid answer assuming a different underlying issue. The question doesn't actually give enough info for an objective answer, so this one fits given that a number was actually being passed.

Comment: ...so if you're going to keep it, you should probably explain *why* it doesn't work. It does work when passing a number,  but integers never start with a leading `0`.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, but the argument being passed will omit 0 if its being passed as an integer, check http://jsfiddle.net/3bFwd/1/